# Bootstrap collapse: Open one, hide other

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 buttons

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" id="collapseSpecificationsButton" href="#collapseSpecifications" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSpecifications">+Spezifikationen</a>\r\n
```

+Zeiten

2 collapse Divs:

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseSpecifications">Content</div>
<div id="collapseTimes" class="collapse">Content</div>
```

and this is my jquery Code in head/script:

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#collapseSpecificationsButton").on("click", function () {
        $("#collapseTimes").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

When I hit the buttons nothing happens, could anybody help me?
How can I debug this?

Comment: Can you look your Javascript console? Is there any errors?

Comment: And dont write $(document).ready inside the head. Because your div is not defined yet it wont see your divs. You should try to write bottom

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but check the Bootstrap docs for "accordion" also. If I understood your question right, is the better approach: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to toggle the content:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#collapseSpecificationsButton").on("click", function() {
         $("#collapseTimes").toggle();
      });
 });
```

if you just want to hide it:

```
$("#collapseTimes").hide();
```